# Reading in text from a file incorrectly

Tags: java

I've got a larger problem with the program but I'm trying to debug it bit by bit. So, I have a text file containing one two three, after each word I have a new line.. so one[new line] two[new line] three. When running the below code it only prints two/three and ignores one. Anyone know this is.....

```
    FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/myname/Desktop/hu.txt");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

    String read;
    read = reader.readLine();

    while((read = reader.readLine())!= null){

        System.out.println(read
  );

    }
```

Comment: Well yes, you've called `readLine()` before the loop, and ignored the result. Just remove the `read = reader.readLine();` statement before the loop... Note that if you'd debugged through the code, you'd have seen this pretty clearly, with `read` being "one" before the loop.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, I really do need to improve myself on these things.... simple stuff like this I should know.

Comment: It's not a matter of *knowing* - it's more important to be able to *diagnose* things (e.g. with a debugger) so that you can work out what's wrong without knowing it beforehand.